# What do the different verbosity levels in Asterisk do?

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to find out what the different verbosity levels in Asterisk mean and what the different levels produce in logging?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk is application which have 100+ DIFFERENT modules. Most of apps developed by DIFFERENT people, some even different organizations.

Asterisk source code have api call like ast_verbose(verbose_level, "strings")

So each developer decide what to say in app and at what verbose level.

You also have Verbose application in dialplan which can be used for same.